# MySQL - Copying table data to non-identical table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have two tables of similar structure, but one is empty and the other has a few rows of information:

table1

```
col1 | col2 | col3
red  | cow  | 1
blue | dog  | 2
gray | pig  | 3
```

table2

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
```

table3

```
col1 | col2
```

Attempting:

```
insert into `table2` select * from `table1`
```

will not work because of the unmatched column count, and the same is true substituting table3 for table2.

Altering the * portion of the SELECT statement is not an option for dynamic purposes. So a workaround would have to be a modified SELECT combining the information.

Is there a JOIN statement or something that would merge the structures of the tables and the data so it would look like this:

```
select * from `table1`,`table2` (JOIN or some other statement)
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
red  | cow  | 1    | NULL
blue | dog  | 2    | NULL
gray | pig  | 3    | NULL

select * from `table1`,`table3` (JOIN or some other statement)
col1 | col2
red  | cow
blue | dog
gray | pig
```

Basically just merging any columns with identical names and nullifying outside matches. Again, it can't refer to specific column names to keep things dynamic. It seems doable, but I'm finding it impossible to find the answer.

Thanks a ton to anybody that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target table of the `INSERT` is a subset of the source table like in your example, then there is a simple solution:

```
insert into table2(col1, col2, col3)
select *
from   table1;
```

Or, if the first columns of both tables are in the same order like in your example, then you your posted query should actually work:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1;
```

I quote the [manual for version 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) on that:

> If you are not running in strict SQL mode, any column not explicitly
>   given a value is set to its default (explicit or implicit) value. For
>   example, if you specify a column list that does not name all the
>   columns in the table, unnamed columns are set to their default values.
>   Default value assignment is described in Section 10.1.4, “Data Type
>   Default Values”. See also Section 1.8.6.2, “Constraints on Invalid
>   Data”.

However, it is **almost always** a bad idea to depend on "SELECT *" in an `INSERT` operation. So, in spite of your request, it really should be:

```
insert into table2(col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, col3
from   table1;
```

For anything more you'll have to use `DESCRIBE tablex` and build your queries dynamically.

Comment: He could also use: `insert into table2 select table1.*, NULL from table1`

Comment: But I definitely agree on your comment on what to **always** use.

Comment: DESCRIBE was to be my last resort, but these answers are making it look like it's my only option. Thanks for your queries, but I think the syntax I'm requesting is more complicated than those.

Answer (score 0):

You could allow null values for the columns that will end up being excluded.

```
insert into `table2` (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 from `table1`
```

may also be of use to you.